# how may I DELETE numbers or symbols after "(" or "["

Tags: r, regex, string

```
names(score)
 [1] "(Intercept)"              "aado2_calc(20,180]"       "aado2_calc(360,460]"     
 [4] "aado2_calc(460,629]"      "albumin[1,1.8]"           "albumin(1.8,2.2]"        
 [7] "albumin(2.2,2.8]"         "aniongap(15,18]"          "aniongap(18,20]"         
[10] "aniongap(20,22]"          "aniongap(22,25]"          "aniongap(25,49]"         
[13] "ethnicityBLACK"           "ethnicityUNKNOWN"         "admission_typeEMERGENCY" 
[16] "electivesurgery"          "mechvent"                 "congestive_heart_failure"
[19] "cardiac_arrhythmias"      "renal_failure"            "liver_disease"           
[22] "lymphoma"                 "metastatic_cancer"        "coagulopathy"            
[25] "obesity"                  "fluid_electrolyte"
```

In this program, I want to delete symbols or numbers behind "(" or "[". For example, "albumin[1,1.8]" should be "albumin".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match either the `(` or (`|`) the `[` followed by one or more number (`[0-9]+`) and the rest of the characters and replace it with blank

```
sub("(\\(|\\[)[0-9]+.*", "",  names(score))
#[1] "(Intercept)"              "aado2_calc"               "aado2_calc"               "aado2_calc"               "albumin"                 
#[6] "albumin"                  "albumin"                  "aniongap"                 "aniongap"                 "aniongap"                
#[11] "aniongap"                 "aniongap"                 "ethnicityBLACK"           "ethnicityUNKNOWN"         "admission_typeEMERGENCY" 
#[16] "electivesurgery"          "mechvent"                 "congestive_heart_failure" "cardiac_arrhythmias"      "renal_failure"           
#[21] "liver_disease"            "lymphoma"                 "metastatic_cancer"        "coagulopathy"             "obesity"                 
#[26] "fluid_electrolyte"
```